# AttributeError: 'UserMF' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In the models.py, please attent there I did not give the `id` in User model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    ...
```

In the ModelForm, I put the `id` in the UserFM:

```
class UserMF(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'phone', 'email')
```

When I get the user's id, I will get the bellow error:

> AttributeError: 'UserMF' object has no attribute 'id'

How to solve this issue, who can help me with that?

---

**EDIT**

When I get the id, the method is bellow:

```
obj = UserMF(request.POST)

if obj.is_valid():
    obj.save()
    xxx = obj.id
```

Comment: show your code when you try to get the `user`

Comment: ID is a default filed of Django model but you can't access it also it's unique and autoincrement

Comment: I do hope you're not creating your own user authentication system and storing passwords raw.

Comment: @MananKalariya not true, you can access it all you want.

Comment: @BearBrown See my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the error more closely; it is telling you that the *form* has no such attribute, which it doesn't.

In order to get a User object from a UserMF instance, you need to validate and save it.

```
form = UserMF(request.POST)
if form.is_valid()
    obj = form.save()
```

Comment: so, what sould I do, need to add the id field in the Model?

Comment: Not this issue, see my edit, I forget to post that is_valid code.

Comment: But you haven't done the right thing. The User instance is *returned* by the save method. Look at my code more closely and copy it *exactly*.